# Is it possible to Build a Qt app targeting Windows XP using Qt 5.12 running on Windows 10?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, windows-xp, legacy

We decided to develop a  POS app which is compatible with Windows XP also , since 40% of small scale shop owners in India are using windows XP system with 512 MB RAM

We decided to try Qt creater since it's C++ based development because C++ based GUI consumes less RAM due to native code complied whereas .Net framework based apps took more memory since it runs above CLR

Now our issue is ,

We came to know that Qt creater stopped support for XP

Now the confusion is , whether the IDE stopped supporting or whole framework stopped support

For instance , Visual studio 2019 don't support XP

But we able to develop XP compatible apps using VS 2019 in windows 10 by Targeting .Net framework 4.0 
.
Now I need to know whether the same procedure also applies for Qt 5.12

That is , Am I able to build a Qt app using Qt 5.12 running in windows 10 by Targeting windows XP by choosing a older versions of Qt framework in the same way I chose .Net 4.0 for XP in VS 2019 ?
.
OR I have to download Qt 5.5 only to build for XP ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use Qt 5.12 to target Windows Xp, you will need to get an older version of Qt, according to [this](https://wiki.qt.io/PlatformSupport) wiki page Qt 5.6 is the newest that still have Xp support.

Also Visual Studio 2019 doesn't support Xp, you will need to install older tool-set (v141) to be able to target Xp, read more on msdn [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/features-deprecated-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/configuring-programs-for-windows-xp?view=vs-2019)

Comment: So sad about using older version. I must support XP. Ok I will try 5.6

Comment: And Does an App developed using Qt takes lesser RAM then a winforms app developed in .Net ?

Comment: It should be more memory efficient, but obviously it depends on what you use and how, so you'll need to measure the memory consumption for your specific needs.